# Prove or disprove that $\lim_{|z|\to \infty}\sin \frac{\pi}{z}=0$

Tags: complex-analysis, limits

> Prove or disprove that $\lim_{|z|\to \infty}\sin \frac{\pi}{z}=0$

I know that $|\sin \frac{\pi}{z}|=|\frac{e^{\frac{i\pi}{z}}-e^{-\frac{i\pi}{z}}}{2i}|=|\frac{e^{\frac{i\pi}{z}}-e^{-\frac{i\pi}{z}}}{2}|$. How do I manipulate this expression. If it would be the case of real valued function, proof is simple.

Comment: Can you consider $\lim_{z\rightarrow \infty}\frac{\pi}{z}$ and then change your formula a bit?

Comment: Since any angle approaches zero when divided by any number that approaches infinity, the sine also zero at the limit.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to manipulate anymore $e^\frac{2\pi i}{z}$ is a continuous function with $\lim_{|z|\rightarrow\infty} e^\frac{2\pi i}{z}=1$ so you have

$$\left|\sin \frac{\pi}{z}\right|=\left|\frac{e^{{i\pi}/{z}}-e^{-{i\pi}/{z}}}{2i}\right|=\left|\frac{e^{{i\pi}/{z}}-e^{-{i\pi}/{z}}}{2}\right|\rightarrow\left|\frac{1-1}{2}\right|=0$$

Comment: at z=0 it has essential singularity. right?

Comment: You only consider $z$ with large $|z|$ so the value at $z=0$ doesn't matter here.

Comment: $$\left |\sin \frac \pi z\right| = |\frac{e^{\frac{i\pi} z}-e^{-\frac{i\pi} z}}{2i}| = |\frac{e^{\frac{i\pi} z}-e^{-\frac{i\pi} z}}{2}| \rightarrow| \frac{1-1} 2|=0$$ $${}$$ $$ \left| \sin \frac \pi z \right| = \left|\frac{e^{i\pi/z}-e^{-\frac{i\pi} z}}{2i}\right| = \left| \frac{e^{i\pi/z} - e^{-i\pi/z}} 2\right| \rightarrow \left|\frac{1-1} 2\right|=0$$ I think 
$e^{\pi i/z}$ is easier to read than $e^{\frac{\pi i} z}.$ And using \left and \right to get the right sizes of delimiters is worthwhile.

Comment: @Mathgeek : Yes: As $z\to0$ along the real axis, $\sin(\pi/z)$ oscillates, and along the imaginary axis it blows up, so this is an essential singularity. If it were a pole the function would approach $\infty. \qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy It looks better now thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Asserting that $\lim_{\lvert z\rvert\to\infty}\left\lvert\sin\left(\frac\pi z\right)\right\rvert=0$ is the same thing as asserting that $\lim_{z\to0}\left\lvert\sin\left(\pi z\right)\right\rvert=0$. It is clear that this holds, since $z\mapsto\sin(\pi z)$ is continuous and it takes the value $0$ at $0$.

Comment: |z| is tending to infinity

Comment: @Mathgeek I've edited my answer. Thank you.